# Как можно сделать эффект плавного открытия картинки

Tags: javascript, css

Как можно сделать эффект, как на этом [сайте](http://optovik55.ru/) . Там оглавление книги, при нажатии на него увеличивается. Как это можно реализовать. Скачал скрипты, которые на том сайте, но ничего не работает.

Comment: Да, сожержание (это вроде одно и то же, или нет?). Там одна картинка имее такой эффект. Очень нужно узнать, как так сделать. Если по коду смотреть, то можно предположить, что используется jcemediabox. Это плагин для JOOMLA, а на сайте вроде воддпресс используется.

Comment: http://crazytimon.blogspot.com/2011/12/blog-post.html тут почитайте, там отличная подборка с хабра, среди них вы найдете то что вам нужно. Ищите в сторону плагинов jquery.
ну и ещё вот http://sixrevisions.com/resources/14-jquery-plugins-for-working-with-images/

Comment: Что-то не нашёл то, что нужно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вы имеете ввиду картинку, которая увеличивается при нажатии, можно либо придумать свой "велосипед" на `jquery`/`js`, либо воспользоватся какой-то из готовых библиотек, таких как [highslide](http://highslide.com/).

Для установки именно этого скрипта, нужно прикрепить к странице скрипт, стили и прописать путь к графическим элементам — всё это хорошо описано на [сайте](http://highslide.com/).

Comment: Что-то не нашёл то, что нужно